# Python call multiprocessing.pool terminate method shut down the entire thread?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using pool in multiprocessing and with django framework. I have the code like this

```
def tokenize(request) :
    global pool
    pool = Pool(processes=32,initializer= compute_customizedStopwords, initargs=()) 
    global canceled
    canceled = False
    for i in range(100) :
        pool.apply(sometask, someargs)
    if canceled :
        return HttpResponse("canceled")
    return HttpResponse("successful!") 

def cancelTokenization(request):
    pool.terminate()
    canceled = True
    return HttpResponse()
```

When the user press the tokenize button, a new web request comes in, and the main process should make a new thread to address this request.But since this function using the multiprocessing. The main process should spwan a bunch of subprocess to run tokenization. But while the tokenization is running, when the urse press cancel, the tokenization process pool should teminate and return "canceled!". But it turns out the front-end never get any response, either successful or canceled. I wonder whether is pool.terminate should shut down the previous running thread in the main proces? How can i implement this  stop function.

Comment: How are you guaranteeing that corresponding tokenize() and cancelTokenization() are always running within the same process (i.e. sharing the pool)?

Comment: I think the tokenize and the cancel should always run in the main process, which the processer which python's web server run on right. When the new cancel request comes, it just make a new thread, and since the pool object is global, so this new thread can directly shut down the pool. If I am corect.

Comment: this definitely depends on how your backend is configured, but most setups will have multiple python processors running and processing requests.  For example, if you use Apache as the web server, you may have multiple Apache processes (workers) serving requests and each worker will have its own instance of python.